# How to decode base64-encoded <data> (CFData/NSData) property in a property list?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, serialization

I am trying to reverse-engineer a preferences file (not for any nefarious purposes, just so that I can script usage of it) that, among other things, has arrays of coordinates stored within it.

This is the salient snippet from the property list:

```
<dict>
  <key>$class</key>
  <dict>
    <key>CF$UID</key>
    <integer>34</integer>
  </dict>
  <key>coordArray</key>
  <data>
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT70vS8/M7xSPwAAAD8AAAA/AAAA
  </data>
  <key>coordCount</key>
  <integer>1</integer>
</dict>
```

I assume that data string is an array of coordinates (based on its key name). My question is, how can I figure out what data is stored there? If I simply base64-decode that string, I get gibberish. Is there a way to decode it and cast it into whatever format it came from (NSArray, I think)?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just load it as a property list and inspect the contents?

```
NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:...];
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution being that the data element, whose contents are base64-encoded in the XML data, would be decoded automatically by the plist parser. The NSData object within the NSDictionary object would contain the decoded data.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I'm a total noob with Objective-C still, and I'm trying to figure out how to write and compile a tiny program that could do this.

Comment: You can get the coordArray from the plist dictionary easily enough.  From there try the various initWithData: methods to see if any of the Foundation class can handle it.  There's no clear way to find out what you have there.

Comment: Maybe because to do that one needs Objective-C development environment and skills.

Answer (score 2):

That dictionary looks like an archived object graph to me; I'd try unarchiving it using `-[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]` (or `-unarchiveObjectWithFile:`).

Comment: Pretty sure they keyed archiver outputs data that's a binary plist.

Comment: It could be that there isn't enough data about the class to unarchive it directly, though.

Comment: I just checked, if it's part of an object graph it's incomplete, so I concede that much; if that's all there is in the full plist, you will probably have to do what Paul suggested and deal with it manually.